# Render HTML tags in kendo template as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a string stored in a SQL database that has carriage returns in it.  I can see the carriage returns via NotePad++.  When I display that string in a kendo template, everything is one long string with no carriage returns.

I have tried a string replace to replace \r\n with `<br \>`.  When I do this, I now see 
 where the line breaks should be.  I thought this was the correct syntax to render HTML tags:

```
<script id="detail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div>
    <span><b>Position Description : </b>#= PositionDescription #</span>
</div>
```

And here are the related definitions in my jquery kendo grid:

```
detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detail-template").html()),
detailInit: function(e) {
                kendo.bind(e.detailRow, e.data);
            },
```

But I get this:

[image: literal]

I have also tried using #: #, but then I get:

[image: literal2]

And here is where I do the replacement (in the Model entity class)

```
position.PositionDescription = position.PositionDescription.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

**UPDATE:**

here is the console logging for e.data:

[image: logging]

Comment: My guess: somewhere along your processing pipeline the linefeeds in the `PositionDescription` value has already been converted to `&lt;br /&gt`. Try looking at e.data in a javascript debugger.

Comment: I see the &lt;br /&gt; in e.data.  I've updated my question with a snapshot of the log results.  Ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that was required was to add the field to the main grid, use Html.Raw, but then hide the column in the main grid.  No changes were necessary in the template or kendo detailInit configuration in jquery.

Main grid HTML:

```
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@item.location.LocationName</td>
                <td>@item.position.department.DepartmentName</td>
                <td>@item.position.PositionName</td>
                <td>@item.PostingID</td>
                <td>@item.PositionID</td>
                <td>@Html.Raw(@item.position.PositionDescription)</td>
                <td>@item.LocationID</td>
                <td>@item.position.DepartmentID</td>
                <td>@item.PostingCreated</td>
                <td>@item.PostingQuantity</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that kendo.bind is used for View Model binding.

You should be doing something like this

```
detailInit: function(e) {
            var template = kendo.template($("#detail-template").html());
            var result = template(e.data);
            $(e.detailRow).html(result);
        },
```

Here is a working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rovuruqi/1/edit

Comment: Your solution works when I use your test data.  However, it does not work when I use my data.  Is there something wrong with the way I'm replacing the line break?

Comment: OK, I fixed it. The solution was to put the column in the main grid, use Html.Raw and then hide that column in the main grid.  I'll post the final solution.